# fwupdx64.efi and fwupdx64.efi.signed cannot be found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fwupdmgr

`sudo fwupdmgr update` fails with the error:

```
/usr/libexec/fwupd/efi/fwupdx64.efi and /usr/libexec/fwupd/efi/fwupdx64.efi.signed cannot be found
```

System information:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
$ uname -a
Linux <hostname> 5.15.0-60-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 14:29:49 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

Install `fwupd-signed`:

```
sudo apt install fwupd-signed
```

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 when I try to install it I have inconsistent dependencies error:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     shim-signed : Breaks: fwupd-signed (< 1.44.1~) but 1.44+1.2-3 is to be installed
    E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.

Comment: I get the same error as @Hpsaturn when trying to install fwupd-signed. However, installing fwupd-unsigned fixed the problem for me - see my post

Answer (score 1):

The problem arises after the `fwupd` package was split, and the signed (for secure boot) and unsigned EFI firmware is shipped with different packages. See

- [fwupdx64.efi ... cannot be found](https://andreas.scherbaum.la/post/2023-04-04_fwupdmgr-usrlibexecfwupdefifwupdx64.efi-and-usrlibexecfwupdefifwupdx64.efi.signed-cannot-be-found/)
- [Unable to update device firmware ...](https://blog.paranoidpenguin.net/2022/03/unable-to-update-device-firmware-fwupdx64-efi-cannot-be-found/)
- [LVFS Triaged Issue: UEFI: fwupdx64.efi cannot be found](https://LVFS%20Triaged%20Issue:%20UEFI:%20fwupdx64.efi%20cannot%20be%20found)
  (where the solution is: *Ensure fwupd-efi is actually installed.*)

In short: install

```
apt-get install fwupd-unsigned
```

and/**or** (if you are using secure boot)

```
apt-get install fwupd-signed
```

Actually - on a system with secure boot disabled - I could not install `fwupd-signed` because of a dependency conflict with `shim-signed` package. (Did not investigate this further.) but installing `fwupd-unsigned` had no problems and solved the issue for me.